# Styling triangle pattern with icon in AngularJS with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to replace all the star character in my pattern with any of the CSS icon. But all I get is only one Icon. The whole h1 tag is replaced by the one star. I can't access every character in the variable to replace with star icon since it is bonded to HTML as an array.

I don't get any clue.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("demo", []);
app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
   console.log("Inside test Controller");
   $scope.temp = "";
   $scope.printStars = function() {
      var n = $scope.givenNumber;
      $scope.values = [];
      $scope.temp = "";
      var i, j, k;
      k = 0;
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

         for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {

            $scope.temp += "* ";

         }

         $scope.values.push($scope.temp)
         k++;
         $scope.temp = "";

      }
   }
});  
</script>

<div class="flex-control-nav" ng-controller="testCtrl">
   <input class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="givenNumber" ng-change="printStars()">
   <h1 class="fa fa-star" ng-repeat=" x in values">{{x}}</h1>
</div>
```

I want the output to be a triangle pattern with an icon but not in the text.

Comment: Hello, first of all there is a typo, a " is missing at the end of the class="" after fa-star. Will fixing that resolve your problem?

Comment: sorry @AndrewAdam I mistakenly forgot to put this in question. This " doesn't do any help.

Comment: I tried your code now and I seem to receive the following format if I type '4' to the number field: 1st row 1 star, 2nd row 2 stars, 3rd row 3 stars and 4th row 4 stars. Is this what you intend to receive?

Comment: yes I want that. But I want the "*" text to be converted to css icon in real star. I cant do that in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have somewhat modified your initial code and it is working now. This is far from perfect but you will get the general idea: it is easy to handle this if you imagine a 2 dimensional array (array of arrays). Like columns and rows. I renamed your variables to better represent this approach.

Also note that I completely removed the "*" string because it is not required at all. In the line where I wrote row.push(j) you could add anything in there instead of j (e.g. the following string: "example") because it does not matter - the ng-repeat will run on each item and the value is not used.

Again, this is far from perfect, but will guide you to the right direction I hope!

```js
var app = angular.module("demo", []);
app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.temp = "";
   $scope.rows = []; // init empty array
   
   $scope.printStars = function() {
      var n = $scope.givenNumber;
      $scope.rows = [];
      
      for(var i = 1; i<=n; i++){
        var row = [];
        for(j = 1; j<=i; j++){
          row.push(j);
        }
        $scope.rows.push(row);
      }
   }
});
```

```css
.row{
  display:inline-block; /* to make sure rows' stars appear next to each other */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div ng-app="demo">
  <div class="flex-control-nav" ng-controller="testCtrl">
     <input class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="givenNumber" ng-change="printStars()">
     <div ng-repeat="x in rows">
        <div ng-repeat="y in x" ng-if="x" class="row">
          <h1 class="fa fa-star" ng-if="y" ></h1>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For cleaner code you could first get rid of the 'ng-if'-s which I added to ensure they are rendered correctly on load (e.g. you could initialize $scope.rows with zero values and opt for an exception for that). Also please not that this approach does not scale well for large numbers (the DOM-rendering can get significantly slower)

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort Adam.Now its working. Now this new code has broaden my overview on this code .Thank you so much  Adam.I was stucked in there for hours since I started learning angularjs yesterday.

Comment: Let us/me know if you need any further help or clarification.

Comment: Thank you adam I will let you know.

Comment: I have a question . If I want to show a diamond with this star icon how can I output space? I know the logic in CPP .its very easy.But in here It seems pretty much challenging to do.Can you give me any suggestion?I want to print a diamond or star with space but outside of it The star will be there .I have completed half of the diamond , the left part. But don't know about printing space so  I am stucked with the right part.

Comment: @DiptoRoy It seems that you wish to better position the stars. For that I would suggest you to read a bit about flexbox and/or css-grid which are the current most advanced positioning attributes. For example what you are looking for could be imagined in the following way: you have a container (the div that has 'flex-control-nav' as class) and within that you want to horizontally center every row. The first row has 1 star, the second 2 stars, the third 3, etc. This way you only have to make sure your rows are centered (which is easy to implement with flexbox).

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ check this tutorial out, one of the most referenced article on flexbox

Comment: Thank you Adam for your help.I will follow this tutorial now.